# Persistence of one to many related objects in play framework 1, duplicate element in list

Tags: playframework, persistence, playframework-1.x

I am trying to understand the following behavior:

If A is defined as:

```
@Entity
public class A extends Model {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    public List<B> bs;
}
```

and B as:

```
@Entity
public class B extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    public A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

First an entity of A is created by calling:

```
public static void prepare() {
    A a = new A().save();
}
```

And then the following action is called:

```
public static void test() {
    List<A> as = A.findAll();
    A a = as.get(0);
    B b = new B(a).save();
    a.bs.add(b);
    System.out.println(a.bs.size()); // ==> 2
}
```

The output is 2 (as B is now twice in A's list). So obviously, when B is saved with the reference on A, A's list is already updated. How does that happen exactly? And what is the difference to the following test:

```
@Test
public void aVeryImportantThingToTest() {
    A a = new A().save();
    B b = new B(a).save();
    a.bs.add(b);
    System.out.println(a.bs.size()); // ==> 1
}
```

(I added a Contructor to A to initialize the list, it does not change the above behaviour.)

Nevertheless, a rule when which behavior is applied would help me already.

Comment: In the first case, do you run the test in two separate (HTTP) requests? In that case, perhaps it's related to the fact that the transaction is committed at the end of the first one.

Comment: Prepare and test are 2 consecutive calls. Commit means stored to the database, right? But I don't see the relation to the A's List.

Comment: Yes, I mean stored to the database. I would suspect that in the first case, A is committed in the first call and once you load it with findAll() in the second, the mapped List<B> bs is already filled with values when fetched.

Comment: but when I load A, its list is empty.